# Placing logo inside multiple areas; header, body, content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I don't know how to explain this, but maybe in this case picture tells story instead of me:

[image: img]

Shortly if you cannot see it. I'm trying to place logo inside multiple areas (header, body, content) like a global image.

Is that possible with CSS, JavaScript, HTML, PHP?

And if it is, any guides or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your logo inside of the `nav` (in this case) section. The logo must be *absolutely positioned*, so that it doesn't mess up with other element's alignment, and your nav section must be *relatively positioned*, so the logo gets placed *in relation to the nav container* (even if it's absolute!).
You didn't provide any HTML/dimensions, so we're pretty much left to guess, but here's how it would look, picking arbitrary dimensions.

```
.nav {
   position: relative;
   height: 100px;
}
/* .logo is a child of .nav */
.logo {
   position: absolute;
   top: -50px;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   left: 0;
}
```

**Take a look:**

```css
body {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.header {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    background: blue;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
}
.body {
    height: 250px;
    background: purple;
}
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> Header </div>
<div class="nav"> 
    <img src="http://www.udavinci.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/stackoverflow.png" class="logo"/>
    Nav 
</div>
<div class="body"> Body </div>
<div class="footer"> My Feet </div>
```

Alternatively, you may also place your logo outside of everything but inside of the `body` tag, and just use `position: absolute`, and tweak it's position (`top`, `left`, etc..), according to the dimensions of the relevant elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your logo in `header` and position with :

```
.your-logo-class {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px; // Adjust this value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: black;}

#top { background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100px; }

#nav { background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 50px; }

#content { background-color: green; width: 400px; height: 500px;  margin: 0 auto;}

#footer { background-color: purple; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <img src="images/logo.png" style="padding: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Or you could add `position: absolute;` to the `img style=""` and then play around with the margin/padding.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, a logo is basically an `<img>` tag, you can place them where ever you like, just give all those `<img>` tags a class and style it the way you want.